# The set of all 2x3 matrices A satisfying A(1;2;3)=(0;0) is a subspace of R^(4x3), and give it dimension.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Prove that the set $V$ of all $2 \times 3$ matrices $A$ satisfying $$A\pmatrix{1\\2\\3}=\pmatrix{0 \\ 0}$$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^{2\times 3}$, and give its dimension.

My first Thought was that make $A=\pmatrix{a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ a_4 & a_5 & a_6}$ then solve.  I ended with a solution with four independent variables.  So I believe that this is enough to say that the set of all possible solutions spans $\Bbb R^{2\times 3}$.

Comment: The question doesn't ask if $V = \Bbb R^{2\times 3}$.  It wants you to use the [subspace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_subspace#Definition_and_useful_characterization_of_subspace) and then specify the dimension of the space.

Answer (score 1):

Saying that there are "four independent variables" does not constitute a subspace. For example, the subset of all vectors in $\Bbb{R}^2$ such that $a_1+a_2+1=0$ is not a subspace despite there being an independent variable. Instead, you should use the [subspace test](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/One-Step_Vector_Subspace_Test).

Let $A, B \in V$ and $c \in \Bbb{R}$. We must show that:
$$A+cB \in V$$
This can be otherwise stated as:
$$(A+Bv)\pmatrix{1\\2\\3}=\pmatrix{0\\0}$$
Distribute on the left-hand side to get:
$$(A+Bv)\pmatrix{1\\2\\3}=A\pmatrix{1\\2\\3}+cB\pmatrix{1\\2\\3}$$
Now, we are given $A, B \in V$, so obviously, those matrices times $\pmatrix{1\\2\\3}$ are $\pmatrix{0\\0}$:
$$(A+Bv)\pmatrix{1\\2\\3}=\pmatrix{0\\0}+c\pmatrix{0\\0}=\pmatrix{0\\0}$$
This proves the equation we wanted, so $V$ is a subspace.

Now, to find the dimension, we set up what you did the first time:
$$\text{Let }A=\pmatrix{a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ a_4 & a_5 & a_6}$$
$$\pmatrix{a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ a_4 & a_5 & a_6}\pmatrix{1\\2\\3}=\pmatrix{0\\0}$$
$$a_1+2a_2+3a_3=0 \\ a_4+2a_5+3a_6=0$$
If we express $A$ as a column vector with $a_i$s rather than a matrix, the above corresponds to the following matrix-vector product equation:
$$\pmatrix{1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3}\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\\a_5\\a_6}=\pmatrix{0\\0}$$
Now, basically, we are finding the dimension of the null space of the matrix on the left. There are two pivot columns and six columns in all, giving us a dimension of $4$.

Answer (score 0):

There are two observations to make here.  The first is that if $v$ is a vector, the map $A\mapsto Av$ is linear.  This is because of the distributive property for matrix multiplication.  The second is that $\{A|Av=0\}$ is the kernel of this linear map, and so we can apply the rank-nullity theorem.

Let us apply this here.  We have a linear map $\mathbb R^{2\times 3}\to \mathbb R^{2}$, and it is straight forward to check that the map is surjective (onto), i.e., it has rank 2.  Since $\dim(\mathbb R^{2\times 3})=6$, and the rank of the map is 2, the nullity (and thus the dimension of the subspace we are interested in) is 4.